# Hamcrest matchers json subarray: is there a way to use hasItems to look for items in a subarray?

Tags: json, matcher, hamcrest, rest-assured

For example, say I had the following json response:

```
{
     "0": {
              "field1" : 5
              "field2" : 10
          }
     "1": {
              "field1" : 1
              "field2" : 10
          }
}
```

Is there some way to verify that field1 has the values 5 and 1? I am stuck at the .body statement here:

```
.body("[0].field1", Matchers.hasItems(1));
```

It is totally possible that I do not completely understand what hasItems is supposed to do, since I tried lots of combinations of [0], [*], and field names and none of them work. I also wish there was a usage article for hamcrest and json that didn't just cover the most basic cases. Does anyone know if what I am asking for is even possible?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your "json document" is not valid. It should probably look like this:

```
{
     "0": {
              "field1" : 5,
              "field2" : 10
          },
     "1": {
              "field1" : 1,
              "field2" : 10
          }
}
```

Since you're targeting a path that matches only a single element you should use the `equalTo` (or `is`) Hamcrest matcher:

```
.body("0.field1", Matchers.equalTo(5));
```

Please note that REST Assured does not use the "Stefan Goessner" JsonPath syntax. It uses the Groovy GPath expression language.